# cordova phonegap Statusbar not working

Tags: ios, cordova, statusbar

Iam working on a iOS project.
I want to setup my statusbar, but it doesn't work.

I added in my config.xml:

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
```

And added the Plugin to my Project:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar
```

But it doesn't work.

My version is cordova 6.3.1

Any ideas?

Comment: try to do a "cordova clean ios". if an option, "cordova platform remove ios ; cordova platform add ios ; cordova build ios" since sometimes cordova will keep cache of generated project

Comment: @Sombriks I tried this, but it doesn't work ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is, I forgot to insert the `cordova.js` file into `index.html`.

Answer (score 1):

In your xcode project, find the projects `.plist` file (which folows the naming convention *projectName-Info.plist)* and add the two following key value pairs to the file:

```
Status bar is initially hidden: YES
View controller-based status bar appearance: NO
```

Tested with Cordova 6.3.1 on iOS 10.0.2